Old cartoon with desert, skeleton, and bad water?
My dad showed me an old cartoon when I was a kid in which the main character is wandering through a desert. He is thirsty and is overjoyed to find a pool of water, when he sees the skeleton of an animal (a steer?) lying nearby. The skeleton speaks and says, "I wouldn't drink that if I were you." 
This scared me so badly when I was little, but I have never been able to find the cartoon since! I seem to remember it being in color, but I could be wrong. Please help! I am going crazy trying to find it.
I remember around the same time watching a cartoon with some dark humor called "Hot Time in the Old Town Tonight," in which little anthropomorphic firefighters are cooked alive into hot dogs and hams. I'm not sure whether the two were related, but it might be a place to start looking if anyone knows where "Hot Time" came from.
Edit: The dialogue was in English, and I'm 95% sure it was American-produced. It was just an episode or short, like a Buggs Bunny cartoon. I think it might have been produced around the 50's or 60's, but my memory of the art style is a bit foggy.

The second part of your question...
Might that be this...? Hot Time in the Old Town Tonight - cartoon
(A.K.A. "The Big Flame-Up")




I was looking for this too- my dad showed me the same one as a kid! 
